# Vue Object Sync using Component and <Select> Input

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I need to sync an Object between a parent and child component in Vue using a `<select>` input but can't get the syntax correct.

*component:*

```
<template>    
  <div>
    <select :value="condition" @change="$emit('update:condition', $event.target.value)">
      <option v-for="variable in variable_options" :value="variable" :key="genUniqueKey(variable)">{{ variable.name }}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  module.exports = {
    props: ['variable_options', 'condition']
  }
</script>
```

I need something like a standard `.sync` modifier, but it doesn't seem to work on select inputs with objects:

```
<variable-select :variable_options="application_questions" :condition.sync="rule.condition">
</variable-select>
```

The `condition` is an object with `id`, `name`, and `type` attributes which come from the `variable` objects in the `variable_options` array. I've tried doing an `initial_condition` prop and then doing a `v-model='selected_condition'` on the `select` input like the docs recommend, but I don't know how to use that with a `.sync` modifier. Doing a `:initial_condition.sync="rule.condition"` isn't right.

Is there a way to pass the object attributes from the selected option in the child component, and update the parent component reactively? The data object's attributes are:

```
rule: {
  condition: {
    id: '',
    name: '',
    type: ''
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Emit `<select>` value

`$event.target.value` refers to [`HTMLSelectElement.value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement), which is a string. This object value would be converted to a string (returning `"[object Object]"`), which would prevent the `.sync` from updating the original object properly.

A workaround would be to use `HTMLSelectElement.selectedIndex` into the `variable_options[]` property:

```
<select @change="$emit('update:condition', variable_options[$event.target.selectedIndex])">
```

#### Default `<select>` value

The default value is set on the `<option>` (not the `<select>`). You could set `<option>.selected` to `true` based on the condition's ID:

```
<option v-for="variable in variable_options"
        :selected="condition.id === variable.id"
        ...>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/llvor0onr9?module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FVariableSelect.vue)

Comment: `$event.target.selectedOptions[0]._value` would be better, I think

Comment: Seems to be updating the parent. However, any ideas why my initial prop value wouldn't be reflected in the initial state of the `<select>` input? It's just defaulting to the first option in the list. `rule.condition` being sent in to the `condition` prop and each `variable` in `variable_options` has the same structure, so I thought it would find the match and reflect that option in the select?

Comment: @TravisSmith The default select value is set by `<option>.selected` (not `<select>.value`).